# undo drag and drop of item

Tags: dynatree, jquery-dynatree

I have a full functional dynatree, where data gets load via ajax (database source), now i enabled drag and drop functionality for the tree. When an item gets dropped i do an ajax request to update the database so node data gets updated. But i do several checks in php to see if node is allowed to be placed on it's "new location".

How can i restore the original location of the node if php rejects the new location where the node is dropped? A full tree reload is possible, but i want to avoid that, and just restore the specific item.

Comment: Can you save the position of the item and then reassign it if it gets rejected by the PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok , i found a correct way to do this. I just do my ajax request to php but set it to an sync (async false), so the dynatree code will wait for the result. Then i implemented a check around the move function of dynatree:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "xxx,
        async: false,
        success: function(data){
            if(data.error == 0){
                showModalOk(data.message);
                phpres = true;
            }else
                phpres = false;
            }

        }
    });

if(phpres == true){
    sourceNode.move(node, hitMode);
    node.expand(true);
}
```

that way the node only gets moved if it's allowed, so no need to restore the node afterwards